# Why am I getting the error E: Package php5-gd has no installation candidate when trying to install php5-gd?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, php

I am trying to install php5-gd and receive this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-gd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package php5-gd has no installation candidate
```

I am not sure why this would be, I checked `dpkg -l | grep php` and noticed php5-gd was installed at one point. I am not sure why it or how it was removed but I need it installed.

```
dpkg -l | grep php
rc  php5-gd                         5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6                          GD module for php5
ii  libapache2-mod-php5             5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6                          server-side, HTML-embedded scripting languag
ii  php5                            5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6                          server-side, HTML-embedded scripting languag
ii  php5-cli                        5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6                          command-line interpreter for the php5 script
ii  php5-common                     5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6                          Common files for packages built from the php
ii  php5-mysql                      5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6                          MySQL module for php5
```

I have checked my sources.list, here it is:

http://pastie.org/7699452 (the paste was too long so I opt'd to use a paste service)

I have ran `apt-get update` as well to be sure.

Could anyone recommend how I can fix this so I can get php5-gd installed?

Comment: Show us output of: apt-cache policy php5-common

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My reputation isn't big enough to comment, but here is what I wanted to say: 
Did you try **adding** another mirror to your sources? Example:
create a new file called `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/alternative_Repo.list` containing this:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted
```

This will make sure that your package manager has access to an up-to-date official mirror in case your main mirror is lagging behind.

I looked at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors and kernel.org is quite behind in many countries. Due to how mirrors works, they can't be up to date all the time.
In the netherlands, as example, it's pretty bad:
`Kernel.org http ftp rsync  1 Gbps  Last update unknown`

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Installation GD.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd && sudo service apache2 restart
```

Some time error in your php library. So try to update also.